# Database trigger - when a field in an updated row equals one of three values, update another table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am having trouble writing a database trigger for mysql. For simplicity sake, I will layout a fake schema and then tell you what the trigger should do:

```
Table A
id
status
base_id

Table B
id
status
A.base_id (foriegn key back to base_id)
```

On update of a record in table A if status is set to one of three values (4,5,6) the trigger needs to update all records in table B that match base_id.

The problem is bit trickier than this but that is the base of the issue and I am new to database triggers and can't seem to get even close. The tables are quite large so the trigger needs to be 'targeted'. In other words, it should not scan the entire table A every time there is any update and update all the records in table B accordingly. It should only update the records in Table B that directly correspond to the single updated row that fires the trigger.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

###################33 UPDATE

This is the trigger as it currently stands but it does not compile. The error is "unknown column 'status' in 'NEW' "

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER db.after_tableA_update
AFTER UPDATE ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

IF NEW.status IN (13,14,15) then
     update tableB as b set b.task_status = 26 where b.match_id = NEW.match_id;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, if i understand you correct. The body of the trigger should be similar to this:

```
BEGIN
IF NEW.status IN(4,5,6) THEN
   UPDATE table_B SET status = NEW.status WHERE base_id = NEW.base_id;
END IF;
END
```

But if you want to update only when status is set to 4,5,6 from another value (also prevents unnecessary queries), you should change if statement to this:

```
BEGIN
IF NEW.status IN(4,5,6) AND OLD.status <=> NEW.status THEN
   UPDATE table_B SET status = NEW.status WHERE base_id = NEW.base_id;
END IF;
END
```

As long as you have an index on `base_id` column of table B and enough memory to cover it, this update query will work very fast.

NOTE: If you have the possibility of doing this in application code, you should avoid using triggers. Triggers in mysql adds significant performance loss even if you do something very simple inside. If this table is not updated often, then it doesnt matter.

Comment: In MYSQL the 'NEW' points to the record that specifically fired the trigger? (Sorry, more of a middleware programmer than a dba). Just to be clear, I don't want to scan the entire database for all records that are = to 4,5,6 and do stuff with all of them. I just want to focus on the record that is updated and if IT is equal to 4,5,6 ... i want to do something to another table

Comment: This is exactly what trigger does. Trigger is executed for each record in mysql, and  `if statement` ensures that it will run update query only in that condition.

Comment: + NEW and OLD keywords points to the same row, but OLD keeps data before modification whereas NEW has modifications.

Comment: Sorry. Last extension to the question. Application code is spaghetti. Trying to find all the places for the status change would be difficult at best. That being said, please define 'performance loss' ?

Comment: Well there are benchmarks out there, but a trigger doing `something` in a write heavy table, may introduce around 30% performance loss coz everytime it triggers it, and do some extra processing for error handling, keeping NEW and OLD variables etc.. Loss coming from internals of mysql.

Comment: This got me close enough. I had some problems with a key word being used as a column name that was what was holding this up. Thanks!